# Another tricky exercise about equivalence relations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, equivalence-relations

> We have the following relation $R \subset \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined as follows: $aRb$ $\iff$ $|a+b|$ is an even number.

No problem showing the relation is reflexive and symetrical but I cannot still figure out why the relation is transitive. I mean, if $|a+b|=2k$ and $|b+c|=2m$ for $k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ how it happens that $|a+c|=2n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? Thanks.

Comment: *Hint:* Sum of two integers even means either both of them even or both of them odd.

Comment: Can you recognize that $|a+b|$ is even if and only if $a-b$ is even?  Now, for transitivity, recognize that $a-b$ is even and $b-c$ is even implies that $(a-b)+(b-c)$ is also even.

Comment: What is $|z|$ in terms of the parity of $z$? Can you make the absolute value function a piecewise function?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $|a+b|$ is even if and only if $a$ and $b$ are of the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! If $|a+b=x|=2k$ and $|b+c=y|=2m$ with $k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then we have that $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, the same argument with $b$ and $c$. Then $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, doesnt matter if both are odd or even we obtain that $|a+c|$ is even. Thanks mates. :)

Comment: What does $|a+b=x|=2k$ even mean??

Comment: You should still prove that $a$ and $b$ must have the same parity from first principles.  Also $|a+b\color{red}{=x}|=2k$ is awkward.  The $=x$ part colored red should not appear.

Comment: $a=2k$ and $b=2l$ then $a+b=2(k+l)$, if $a=2k+1$ and $b=2l+1$ then $a+b=2(k+l+1)$, so in both cases $a+b$ is even. The notations $x=a+b$ is not necessary, sorry.